# Authentication using Angular 8 with Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, angular, azure, authentication

I am having some issues of finding forums/tutorials/examples on how to fully authenticate an angular app with Azure Active Directory. So in short, I need to log in to the user via angular 8 and I am using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular library which I found really good and easy. I am retrieving the token id and the user after login. The issue is, that I need to add that user to the Database because I have like a role management system which I need to add the user in the aspnet users db. I need to call an api which needs to authenticate that the user is real from .net side and then add the user to the aspnet users db. If he's already existing there so it just need to authenticate him and create a token. I need to know example of .net on how to populate the User.Identy with the user. I am sending the api 2 headers, Authorization which is the bearer token id and access token. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're using aspnet core, you just need a middleware which will validate your JWT token acquired from the front end, and check if the user / token are valid (and also populate the User.Identity for you).

More info: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Azure/AzureAD/samples/AzureADSample

EDIT:
for asp.net mvc (non core), you'll do the same approach:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-ad-authentication-for-mvc-web-application/

Comment: No I am not using aspnet core because this project started before aspnet core was introduced. Am using webapi. Is there any examples please?

Comment: sure, same approach but you'll need a filter which will receive the JWT and validate against azure ad.

Answer (score 0):

No I am not using aspnet core because this project started before aspnet core was introduced. Am using webapi. Is there any examples please?